# buy an Item more than one in windows store application

Tags: microsoft-metro, in-app-purchase

I need to buy some products in metro application two or three or more times to same user ,the regular in app purchase for windows 8 supports this type of purchase?

Comment: Do you mean consumables vs. durables purchases?

Comment: Yes I mean consumable purchase,but I saw consumable purchases in windows phone 8,I need it in metro application for windows 8

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about in-app purchases of multiple *different* products, that's straightforward to do, and detailed in this article and sample:

- [How to support in-app purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067)
- [Trial app and in-app purchase sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a)

However, it sounds like you're talking about consumables - e.g. buy a pack of gold coins for your character in the game, and allow the user to buy that pack multiple times.

That kind of purchase is not directly supported for Windows Store apps (though the Windows Phone SDK has [ProductLicense.IsConsumable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense.isconsumable)), but there is a type of [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/07222726-3adc-4d49-91d7-ed64381b8057) that you may find helpful, depending on your scenario.

Comment: Ah, just refreshed and saw your clarifying comment.  I'll leave the extra parts of the answers in for others' reference.

Comment: chris? I decided to not check if the product is active or not before calling purchase method,it works in simulator but will it work on store?

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows 8 Store consumable purchase hasn't implemented yet,but there is a workaround,if you need to sell an item (i.e book1) 2,3 or more times you need to define it in the Windows store with different names like book1_1 and book1_2 ,when user taps buy button you sell book_1  and second time you sell book1_2 ,if you need you can define book1_3 and 4,5,....